# Two web applications on same domain

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server

I installed 2 different web applications on my dedicated Debian 6. the first one sits inside /var/www/cast and the url assigned is `

> example.example.com/cast

`

I installed the second one that is called Airtime.the second instalation didnt offer an install path so it installed automaticaly somewhere..now whenever i try to enter the first one i get the second one..if i try

> example.example.com/cast

it leads to Airtime. if i go to

> example.example.com

it also lead there..

This is the enries on airtime-vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.example.com
      #ServerAlias www.example.com

      ServerAdmin example@gmail.com

      DocumentRoot /usr/share/airtime/public
      DirectoryIndex index.php

      SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"

      <Directory /usr/share/airtime/public>
              Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Order allow,deny
              Allow from all
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any thoughts on how i can give them both a unique url?

Comment: Do you own the domain, and can you create additional subdomains for it? Also, you might want to replace the domain with `subdomain.example.com` unless you want everyone that views this question to visit it and possibly start snooping around.

Comment: thanx for the tip m8...i have root access but i dont own the domain..

Comment: its a rented dedicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like Airtime comes with its own web server, but "cast (whatever that is) doesn't. Is this correct?

Anyway, the general problem can be handled in many ways:

- You can run both applications within the same web server, if possible. This would only be impossible if one of the applications depends on a very specific version of the web server (assuming Apache based on the Airtime config file) that is incompatible with the other application. But if you can get all the requisite Apache modules loaded into a single instance of Apache, sufficient to run both apps, then yes, you just have to put each application in a separate path within the document root, e.g. /var/www/airtime and /var/www/cast, and it'll "just work". Alternately, you can map any directory in the filesystem into the document root, either by simlinking into /var/www, or by Apache config directives.
- You can run two different web servers but run them on different ports. This will change the URL to at least one of the instances to require a port number after the domain, e.g. `http://example.com:8080/blah` where the `:8080` is the port (I recommend choosing a value greater than 1024 but less than 65000, and google the number before using it to make sure it's not a well known port for a service you are already running).
- You can run two different web servers but run them on different IP addresses. You can keep the port default at 80 (or 443 for `https`) this way, but you'll need two different IPs.
- You can run two different web servers but run them on the same IP address but on different subdomains. You can then use URL Rewriting to automatically map requests to `http://airtime.example.com` to the airtime application and from `http://cast.example.com` to the cast application.
- For all of the above, you can even do it within one web server if the configuration is robust enough -- and the Apache web server is robust enough to do all of the above within one web server instance, although you'll need some more exotic configuration settings for some of the choices. Note that I highly recommend trying to run it all within one web server instance **first**, because this way is more flexible and easier to manage, plus you probably can configure it without having to worry about ports or IP addresses, which complicate things for your users in the former case and for you in the latter case.

The problem with the Airtime config is that it's trying to be a vhost for `*:80` which means that every request to your server on port 80 is going to be mapped into the document root for airtime, i.e. `/usr/share/airtime/public`. You need to get both the `cast` application and the `airtime` application within the same vhost, or else, constrain the vhost of airtime from `*:80` to something like `airtime.example.com:80` so that only requests to that subdomain will get passed to airtime.

Your Apache config that comes builtin with Debian is at `/etc/apache2/` directory, so go there and look at `apache.conf`. Notice that it also has a `<VirtualHost *:80>` directive. Well, you can't have two virtual hosts claiming to handle all requests on port 80; only one of them can win. Therein lies the problem.

Comment: hey buddy thanx for the reply..from all the options you suggested..changing the port for airtime would be ideal..how can i do that? if i change the 80 to 2199 for example..i get Restarting web server: apache2[Wed Aug 15 17:04:47 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting [Wed Aug 15 17:04:48 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
when restarting the apache

Comment: Make sure the `/var/www/cast`'s vhost config is still running on port 80.

Comment: not quite sure how..but ill figure it out, thanx guys,